# Solaris 11: zfs smb share works only as guest

Tags: solaris, samba, zfs, cifs, smb

I'm on Solaris 11.4

I create a zfs fs

```
zfs create rpool/share
```

and I set for sharing via smb

```
zfs set share=name=zfssmb1,path=/rpool/share,prot=smb,csc=auto,guestok=false rpool/share
```

When I try to access via smbclient from any client..

```
smbclient \\\\solaris11.mydomain.local\zfssmb1 -U myuser%mypass -w mydomain
```

give me access denied.
And on /var/adm/messages said..

```
SOLARIS11\guest]: (10.3.0.225) zfssmb1 access denied: guest disabled
```

If I enable the guest access I can access via smbclient without problems

```
zfs set share=name=zfssmb1,path=/rpool/share,prot=smb,csc=auto,guestok=true rpool/share
```

I try to set idmap but nothing change

```
idmap add winuser:*@mydomain.local unixuser:*
idmap add "wingroup:Domain Users@mydomain.local" unixgroup:users
idmap add "wingroup:Domain Admins@mydomain.local" unixgroup:staff
```

EDIT1: A little progress

After enabling my user via smbadm

```
smbadm enable user myuser
```

and edit /etc/pam.d/other

```
password required       pam_smb_passwd.so.1 nowarn
```

I can mount sucesfully the share from Solaris client

```
mount -o user=myuser -F smbfs //solaris11/zfssmb1 /mnt
```

But Linux clients and smbclient on Linux and Solaris return logon failure

```
mount.cifs \\\\solaris11.mydomain.local\\zfssmb1 -o user=myuser,password=*******

smbclient \\\\solaris11.mydomain.local\\zfssmb1 -U myuser%mypass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, the complete solution is here

a)create a zfs fs

```
zfs create rpool/share
```

b)set for sharing via smb

```
zfs set share=name=zfssmb1,path=/rpool/share,prot=smb,csc=auto,guestok=false rpool/share
```

c)set user via smbadm

```
smbadm enable user myuser
```

d) add key

```
smbadm add-key -u myuser
```

e)edit /etc/pam.d/other and place this line on the end of file

```
password required       pam_smb_passwd.so.1 nowarn
```

f)now most important, change the password, this command enable both unix and samba pass

```
passwd myuser
```

g)now try if work, this commands from a Solaris client must run fine

```
smbclient \\\\solaris11.mydomain.local\\zfssmb1 -U myuser%mypass
```

h) and also those from a Linux client

```
mount.cifs \\\\solaris11.mydomain.local\\zfssmb1 -o user=myuser,password=yourpass,vers=1.0 /mnt

smbclient \\\\solaris11.mydomain.local\\zfssmb1 -U myuser%mypass
```